# While creating object of class, it throws an error

Tags: javascript

```
class A{
    constructor(){
        this.name="A";
    }
    M1(){
        return "M1";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    constructor(){
        this.id="B";
    }
    M2(){
        return "M2";
    }
}

var b = new B();
```

**output:**

> ReferenceError: this is not defined
>       at B (repl:4:1)
>       at repl:1:9
>       at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
>       at bound (domain.js:287:14)
>       at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
>       at REPLServer. (repl.js:431:12)
>       at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
>       at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call **super's** constructor.When you call the base class constructor it creates the `this` and then you can use `this`.

```
class A{
    constructor(){
        this.name="A";
    }
    M1(){
        return "M1";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.id="B";
    }
    M2(){
        return "M2";
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

The reason why you need to call the super-constructor from a derived class constructor is due to where ES6 allocates instances – they are allocated by/in the base class (this is necessary so that constructors can be subclassed that have exotic instances, e.g. Array):

```
// Base class
class A {
    // Allocate instance here (done by JS engine)
    constructor() {}
}
// Derived class
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        // no `this` available, yet
        super(); // receive instance from A
        // can use `this` now
    }
}
// Derived class
class C extends B {
    constructor() {
        // no `this` available, yet
        super(); // receive instance from B
        // can use `this` now
    }
}
```

Thanks to **Axel Rauschmayer**.
For more see here https://esdiscuss.org/topic/super-on-class-that-extends

Comment: Hi Suren, could you please explain it more.

Comment: Thanks @Suren for your help.